# VScode settings.json show error "End of file expected"

Tags: visual-studio-code

This code is my VScode settings.json.
but i don't know why it show 
`"End of file expected" jsonc(0) [5, 1]`

begin i just want input int on my terminal.
but it can't,so i open Run in Terminal 
'v' Whether to run code in integrated terminal.
and
pop out
`'Failed to write user settings. Please turn it on to correct any errors / warnings and try again.'`

and try setting
run code config
select run in terminal
pop out again
`'Failed to write user settings. Please turn it on to correct any errors / warnings and try again.'`

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 60
}
{
    // Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    },

    // Controls if suggestions should be accepted on 'Enter' - in addition to 'Tab'. Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines or accepting suggestions. The value 'smart' means only accept a suggestion with Enter when it makes a textual change
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on",

    // Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,

    // Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true,

    // Controls if pressing tab inserts the best suggestion and if tab cycles through other suggestions
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",

    // Controls whether sorting favours words that appear close to the cursor
    "editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,

    // Controls how suggestions are pre-selected when showing the suggest list
    "editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed",

    // Enable word based suggestions
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,

    // Enable parameter hints
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't known. 
before i delete after [5, 1]. It will be normal.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `} {`

```
{
  "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
  "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 60, // add comma to end here
// } --<  remove this -----------------------------------------
// { --<  remove this too -----------------------------------------
 ..... rest is good
```